# Angular Google Map on multiple Tabs with same Controller and same Template

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps, tabs, ionic-framework

I'm working with IONIC and AngularJS and have a Google Map included. I have a template and a Controller for this map and I will use the map on two Tabs.

```
.state('tab.map1', {
  url: '/tab1/map',
  views: {
    'map1-tab': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
      controller: 'MapController'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.map2', {
  url: '/tab2/map',
  views: {
    'map2-tab': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
      controller: 'MapController'
    }
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

URL on the first Tab:
**/tab1/map**

URL on the second Tab:
**/tab2/map**

Now when I call one of the URL's everything is fine and I can see my map. But when I change the tab I can't see the map anymore. the div seems to be empty. After page reload, the map is visible.
Does anybody knwo how to deal with the "same" page on multiple tabs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If someone else has the same issue, here my solution:

The problem was, that I used the same HTML for both tabs, the div's shouldn't have the same id.

```
.state('tab.map1', {
  url: '/tab1/map',
  views: {
    'map1-tab': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/map1.html',
      controller: 'MapController'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.map2', {
  url: '/tab2/map',
  views: {
    'map2-tab': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/map2.html',
      controller: 'MapController'
    }
  }
})
```

HTML for first Tab:

```
<div id="map1"></div>
```

HTML for second Tab:

```
<div id="map2"></div>
```

And in my controller logic

```
if ($location.path() == 'tab1\map'){
  $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), mapOptions);
}else{
  $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions);
}
```

That is working for me, map is always visible when changing between tabs.

Comment: yes, looks like google map enforcing the one instance per app by holding onto the element. when you instantiate the map with the same element, it will throw an exception. which means one must keep that page in the navigation stack (in this case, it's in the tab, tab will hold one to all its tab pages).

Comment: i mean one instance per element which is bad, that means one need to keep that page in the DOM, this prevent some of the navigation scenarios with ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is a start, you will need two instances of the map. if that still doesn't work, try triggering a google map 'resize' when returning to the map page:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#event

(I had a similar issue in ionic 2, in which I solved it by using the Navigation array to push and pop each page rather than navigating to it, but I believe Ionic 1 uses actual URL paths.)

Comment: having the same issue with google map, when navigating to it, google.maps.Map(..) constructor throw an exception. how did you use Navigation array to push/pop the page? currently using this.nav.push(MapPage, data) to navigating to the map page. thx!

Comment: I see what you are saying, so your map page is never unloaded. just like another tab page that stays there but not visible. but that wont' work for my scenario, i need to show the location base on the user's selection and center that location.